# how can we print request and response on t3 protocol of weblogic?

Tags: logging, weblogic, protocols

I am trying to print request response on t3 protocol [inter weblogic]. I was able to find same for http one where browser client is hitting weblogic by http protocol. Is there similar settings for t3?

HTTPS

```
export JAVA_OPTIONS=" ${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.webservice.verbose=true"
export JAVA_OPTIONS=" ${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true"
export JAVA_OPTIONS=" ${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true"
export JAVA_OPTIONS=" ${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true"
export JAVA_OPTIONS=" ${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true"
```

Comment: T3 is a binary protocol, WLS does not provide such a functionality, i'm afraid you have to code it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for clarification !